# Broken timer or something else

Tags: c++, c

I have some program what must help me, but i cant handle timing. 
Hire is a code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

double diffclock(clock_t clock1) {
    clock_t clock2 = clock();
    double diffticks = clock1 - clock2;
    double diffms = diffticks / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);

    return diffms;
}


int main()
{
    int wait = 134;
    clock_t fullbetween = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Sleep(wait / 5);
        cout << wait / 5 << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl << "finish in " << diffclock(fullbetween) << " ms" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

C++ version. same result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>


int main()
{
    int wait = 134;
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(wait/5));
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto int_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds> (end - start);

    std::cout << std::endl << "finish in " << int_ms.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

134 / 5 = 26 is ok. But in last "cout" it shows that all that iteration taked about ~170ms, not 130 as expected. Why this is happening ?

Sry about my engl.

Comment: `time.h` is not a C++ header. You tagged C++ so use `ctime`

Comment: `Sleep()` is not C++ but some (obscure?) Windows thing. You should stick to standard C++ , see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the Sleep function at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep says

> Suspends the execution of the current thread until the time-out interval elapses.
>
> The system clock "ticks" at a constant rate. If dwMilliseconds is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time. If dwMilliseconds is greater than one tick but less than two, the wait can be anywhere between one and two ticks, and so on.

Ticks are typically 15.6 ms on Windows systems (64 ticks per second), so 26 becomes 31.2.
This is the time after which it is possible for the suspended thread to become active again, there is no guarantee that it will start executing immediately. So your five sleeps become 156ms plus a little overhead.

The documentation continues with mitigations for this behaviour, and warnings that the mitigations will affect system power usage and so on.

> To increase the accuracy of the sleep interval, call the timeGetDevCaps function to determine the supported minimum timer resolution and the timeBeginPeriod function to set the timer resolution to its minimum.

Comment: didnt know it, tnx!

Answer (score 1):

In std::this_thread::sleep_for documentation (found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for))

> It is stated that the function blocks the execution of the current
> thread for at least the specified sleep_duration.
>
> It may block for
> longer than sleep_duration due to scheduling or resource contention
> delays.

So your code will take at least 135ms to execute.